# Matlab: dynamically storing objects, alternatives to containers.Map class

Tags: matlab, oop, key, containers

I have code in which there are many objects, where each is referenced by its own numeric ID/pointer. I wish to store these objects in some sort of structure where I can reference the objects from the structure using their numeric ID. However, the IDs are not sequential, and I don't want to allocate space for all of the non-existent IDs. This rules out simply creating an object array.

I'm currently using the [containers.Map](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html) class which stores values/objects with lookup keys, but it's rather slow. Are there any alternatives?

As an example, this code would create a containers.Map object, `map` filled with fictional objects:

```
%create object storage container which uses uint32 keys and can store values of any class
map = containers.Map('KeyType','uint32','ValueType','Any');

%construct objects with ID property, and store in map
for ID = [8 230 755 67 102]
    map(ID) = example_obj(ID)
end
```

Is there anything that could replace the containers.Map `map` object in this code which wouldn't allocate space for all of the non-present IDs from 1 to 755?

Comment: Maybe not very clean, but have you thought about creating a second array which stores your keys and index your object array via this second array?

Comment: How is this rather slow?  You also can initialize a `containers.Map` right away without having to populate the key/value pairs iteratively?

Comment: In reply to Ihcheneva, that's not a bad idea. I think the array of keys would still have to be the length of the highest key, but I suppose I could always use a sparse matrix. The only problem is that objects are constantly being added and removed, which would require restructuring the object-array.

Comment: Creating the `containers.Map` is not necessarily what is slow, but to read and write the properties of an object in the map, you have to create a duplicate object, `temp_obj = map(ID)` then call upon its properties. Pulling objects out of the map is what's slow. Ideally I'd be able to do something like this: `map(ID).property`

Comment: Have you tried with handle objects? If you define your object class as derived from handle class then they behave as pointers, so you will be able to create an array of pointers. A cell array would allow you to remove components easily.

Comment: This might be kind of slow but have you considered using the Java libraries? Possibly import a Linked List implementation?

Comment: An [array of structures](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/04/22/matlab-basics-array-of-structures-vs-structures-of-arrays/)?

Comment: If your ids only go up to 755, just use a cell array. Sure it feels dumb and wastes a tiny bit of memory, but who cares?

You could also create a new id so that the ids ARE sequential.

Comment: @alexmogavero, I have tried using handle objects, but this only allows me to change object properties without rewriting them back into the map. i.e., changing the properties of an object copied from the map, such as those of `temp_obj = map(ID)` will change the properties of the object stored in the map if the object is a handle object. However, one still has to create a copy of the object outside of the map, which is slow.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. A while ago I ruled out using cell arrays because I thought they would be too wasteful (my actual code often has IDs exceeding 1 million), but I never tested it. I think I'll do so now, and look into using the Java libraries, which I didn't know was possible. I'll post back after I do some testing.

Comment: @Jeremy creating a copy of an handle object should not be slow because it actually will not be copied and only a pointer to it will be created. Creating then a cell array with instances of handle object should be quite fast.